# Bash - command not found, but still works

Tags: bash

I wrote such a code for audio volume modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
        down)
            $(amixer -c 0 sset Speaker  5%-)
            $(amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-)  
            ;;  
        up)
            $(amixer -c 0 sset Speaker  5%+)
            $(amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+)
            ;;
        mute)
            $(amixer -c 0 sset Speaker  0)
            $(amixer -D pulse sset Master 0)
            ;;
        *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {down|up|mute}"
            exit 1
esac
```

Well the code works ok, however when I execute it in the terminal i got following information:

```
[akfaz@localhost utils]$ ./audioControl.sh up
./audioControl.sh: line 9: Simple: command not found
./audioControl.sh: line 10: Simple: command not found
```

Do You have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove all command substitutions: `$( )`, they are not needed.

It's needed when you have to return the result of the command inside, like when feeding a variable:

```
var=$(echo "ok")
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Comment: You might want to add an explanation like "The output of the commands seems to be sth like 'Simple values are not used' (or whatever text starting with 'Simple'), so 'Simple' is taken as the command to execute, hence the error message."

Comment: Thanks for explaining a bit more.